# Custom-made linspace and logspace in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I decided to take a look at two functions `linspace` and `logspace`. Below I give two examples, one using MATLAB's built-in `linspace` and one for `logspace` along with their hand made implementation. In the first case both the built-in function `linspace` and the handmade code give the same results.  However, this is not true when examining the `logspace` function. Could you please help me to found the error in the handmade code?

```
a = 1; b = 5; n = 7;
y = linspace(1,5,7);
yy = zeros(1,n); yy(1) = a;
for i=2:n
    yy(i) = yy(i-1) + (b-a)/(n-1); 
end

x = logspace(1,5,7);
xx = zeros(1,n); xx(1) = 10^a;
for i=2:n
    xx(i) = xx(i-1) + (10^b-10^a)/(n-1); 
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look inside the MATLAB builtin function by typing `edit logspace`. You will notice that internally it is actually using `linspace`. You should be able to easily figure out the difference compared to your own version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between `linspace` and `logspace` is that they go one step further and take the power of 10 for every element in the `linspace` array.

As such, you'd simply take your equation for `linspace` you generated, take the result and raise it to the power of 10.  However, with your code, you are relying on the previous result and that is already raised to the power of 10.  Therefore, you'll need to take the anti-log to convert the previous result back to a linear form, then use the same logic was used to generate the `linspace`, then raise it back to the power of 10.  Therefore, the relationship is:

```
xx[n] = 10^(log10(xx[n-1]) + ((b-a)/(n-1)))
```

You can certainly simplify this, taking advantage of the fact that `10^(log10(z)) = z`, as long as `z > 0`.  We can also split up the terms in the power using the property that `10^(m + n) = (10^m) * (10^n)`.  Therefore:

```
xx[n] = xx[n-1] * (10^((b-a)/(n-1)))
```

As such, simply take your previous result **multiply** with `10^((b-a)/(n-1))`

```
a = 1; b = 5; n = 7;

x = logspace(1,5,7);
xx = zeros(1,n); xx(1) = 10^a;
for i=2:n
    xx(i) = xx(i-1)*(10^((b-a)/(n-1))); %// Change 
end
```

We get for both `x` and `xx`:

```
>> format long g;
>> x

x =

  Columns 1 through 4

                        10          46.4158883361278          215.443469003188                      1000

  Columns 5 through 7

          4641.58883361278          21544.3469003189                    100000

>> xx

xx =

  Columns 1 through 4

                        10          46.4158883361278          215.443469003188                      1000

  Columns 5 through 7

          4641.58883361278          21544.3469003188                    100000
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was confused from the mathworks expanation: `y = logspace(a,b,n) generates n points between decades 10^a and 10^b.` Based on this explanation I followed the same logic as in `linespace`. It is just the `linspace` results raised on the 10th power. Thanks!

Comment: @Darkmoor correct :) If you **don't** want to rely on using the results from `linspace`, you can use what I wrote above just using your `logspace` array.  Good luck!